# WMTS from MapProxy in QGIS and/or ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.1, qgis-2, mapproxy, wmts

My company wants to use imagery from a another company internally for a contract. That company's WMS has a 5+ second latency. Which I'm told is unacceptably slow. So I set up MapProxy and seeded the cache locally. Latency is now about 1-2 seconds. My boss' boss' boss would like to see if WMTS would be faster. So, I turn on the WMTS layer...and nothing. Researching the problem I see that MapProxy defaults it's origin to the lower left corner, but WMTS expects upper left. So I changed that setting, deleted the cache, and made a new one using the new data. Still no WMTS. QGIS seems to be sending requests and MapProxy is reporting 200, but I see nothing rendered. ArcGIS failed to understand the request at all it seems, at least it wasn't able to read the bounds. I know I'm adding the layer correctly in QGIS (2.0.1) because I can add publicly available WMTS services no problem. When I copy the url into the browser it displays the image no problem. I've tried both Restful and KVP versions. Nothing. MapProxy is running on Centos 6 if it matters.

I have attached the GetCapabilities.xml documents. (Identifying information has to be removed as per company requirements.)

[Restful WMTS Service](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xekmphfohgq2ubk/MapProxy_WMTS_Restful_GetCap.xml)

[KVP WMTS Service](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aofndhbsea7ig8o/MapProxy_WMTS_KVP_GetCap.xml)

MapProxy Configuration:

The WMTS is simply turned on, no special modifications.

Cache:

```
caches:
  Imagery_Cache:
    meta_size: [5, 5]
    meta_buffer: 20
    format: image/jpeg
    request_format: image/jpeg
    grids: [my_grid]
    sources: [Imagery_source]
    cache:
      type: file
      directory_layout: tc
      directory: /data/mapproxy/folder
```

sources:

```
sources:
  Imagery_source:
    type: wms
    supported_srs: ['EPSG:4326']
    req:
      url: "https://is.this/a/url?"
      layers: Imagery
    http:
      ssl_no_cert_checks: True
```

grids:

```
grids:
  my_grid:
    base: GLOBAL_GEODETIC
    bbox: [##.# ##.#,##.# ##.#]
    bbox_srs: EPSG:4326
    origin: ul
```

globals:

```
globals:
  cache:
    base_dir: './cache_data'
    lock_dir: './cache_data/locks'
    tile_lock_dir: './cache_data/tile_locks'
    meta_size: [4, 4]
    meta_buffer: 80

  image:
    resampling_method: bicubic
    stretch_factor: 1.15
    max_shrink_factor: 4.0
    paletted: false
    formats:
      custom_format:
        format: image/png
        mode: P
        colors: 32
        transparent: true
        encoding_options:
          quantizer: fastoctree
      image/jpeg:
        encoding_options:
          jpeg_quality: 60
```

So, any thoughts as to what is wrong and how I can get the WMTS to serve up properly?

Comment: Bshender, have you been able to resolve this issue? I am experiencing the same problems when trying to open WMTS by Mappoxy in ArcGIS 10.1: it can read the capabilities and display the layer list, but when adding layers to the map, they are not rendered, and their properties are missing spatial extent and reference information. QGIS 2.2.0 opens the same WMTS layers just fine. When comparing my WMTS capabilities with the publicly available ones (they render in ArcGIS 10.1), I see that in Mapproxy generated file WellKnownScaleSet tag is missing from TileMatrixSet tag, and also ows:SupportedCRS t

Comment: No I have never figured this one out. If you do I would love to hear the answer.

Comment: oops, looks like the ending got cut off: "...and also ows:SupportedCRS tag is provided as simply EPSG:3857 instead of urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.18:3:3857. Not sure how to modify these values for Mapproxy generated capabilities though." I tested my WMTS in ArcGIS 10.2.1 and it opened without a problem. Release notes for ArcGIS 10.2 include lots of fixes for WMTS. So, I am inclined to blame this on ArcGIS version.